# How to adjust your slider in the middle with two image in the left and two in the right (both in a same div)?

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner to html and CSS and want to adjust my slider in the middle where on the left and right side there are two images both in a same div with same class name.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="GR.css">
<title>GR PROVIDER</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="WARPER">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="Header">
            <div class="heading">
            <div class="title">
            <h2> Gulf Resources Provider </h2>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="socialmedia">
            <ul class="OList">
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/Facebook.jpg"> </a> </li>
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/LinkedIn.jpg"></a> </li>
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/Google.jpg"> </a> </li>
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/Twitter.jpg"> </a> </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="images">
            <div class="pics">
            <img class="snaps" src="GRProvider/Img.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="pics">
            <img class="snaps" src="GRProvider/Img_2.jpg"/>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main_content">
            <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="list">
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> HOME </a> </li>
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> ABOUT US </a> </li>
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> CAREER </a> </li>
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> CONTACT US </a> </li>
            </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="Slider">
            <div class="slider_img">
            <img src="GRProvider/Slider.jpg">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="images">
            <div class="pics">
            <img class="snaps" src="GRProvider/Img_3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="pics">
            <img class="snaps" src="GRProvider/Img_4.jpg"/>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Info">
            <div class="About_Us">
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting indutry. Lorem Ipsum has been 
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has 
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has  Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsum............. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
            <button type="button"> READ MORE </button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
            <div class="text">
            <img src="GRProvider/Img_4.jpg" />
            <h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
            <p> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any  
            varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do 
            feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae 
            consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, 
            eros leo molestie velit, nonegestas augue nulla </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
            <img src="GRProvider/Img_5.jpg" />
            <h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
            <p> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any  
            varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do 
            feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae 
            consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, 
            eros leo molestie velit, nonegestas augue nulla </p>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
            <img src="GRProvider/Img_6.jpg" />
            <h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
            <p> consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any  
            varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do 
            feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae 
            consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, 
            eros leo molestie velit, nonegestas augue nulla </p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
            <h3> Copyright by Bitsprovider.com </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        background-color: #1e93a5;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
    }
    .header {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .heading {
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
    }
    .title {
        width: 70%;
    }
    .socialmedia {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .OList {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ListItem {
        list-style: outside none none;
        width: 40%;
    }
    .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .Social {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .images {
        width: 32%;
    }
    .pics {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .snaps {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main_content {
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
    }
    .navigation {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .slider {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .slider_img {
        width: 60%;
    }
    .list {
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .LType {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .NLinks {
        width: 14%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle? that'd be better

Comment: What is mean by fiddle???

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net - this is fiddle. You can excecute your code in this space. Google it for more info.

Comment: Can you please check what's going wrong in my code...

Comment: I'm checking right now. you want the main image on the left and other two images on the right ?

Comment: I want my two images on the left and two on the right both in the same div, with slider in the middle. Can I share my design image with you...?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want something like this. your markup wasn't right. I just cleaned up your html and css a bit.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e93a5;
  margin: 0;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.heading {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}
.title {
  width: 70%;
}
.socialmedia {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
.OList {
  width: 100%;
}
.ListItem {
  list-style: outside none none;
  width: 40%;
}
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.Social {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.images {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.pics {
  /*width: 20%;*/
}
.snaps {
  width: 100%;
  height: 61px;
}
.main_content {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
}
.Slider {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.slider_img {
  /*width: 60%;*/
}
.list {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.LType {
  width: 25%;
}
.NLinks {
  width: 14%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.slider_img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
}
.clearfix {
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="GR.css">
  <title>GR PROVIDER</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="WARPER">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="Header">
        <div class="heading">
          <div class="title">
            <h2> Gulf Resources Provider </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="socialmedia">
          <ul class="OList">
            <!--  <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/Facebook.jpg"> </a> </li>
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/LinkedIn.jpg"></a> </li>
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/Google.jpg"> </a> </li>
            <li class="ListItem"> <a class="link" href=""> <img class="Social" src="GRProvider/Twitter.jpg"> </a> </li> -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="main_content">
        <div class="navigation">
          <ul class="list">
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> HOME </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> ABOUT US </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> CAREER </a> 
            </li>
            <li class="LType"> <a class="NLinks" href="#"> CONTACT US </a> 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">

          <div class="images">
            <div class="pics">
              <img class="snaps" src="http://www.vectordiary.com/isd_premium/048-hot-air-balloon/hot-air-balloon.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="pics">
              <img class="snaps" src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3491/4065563881_d023aaf065.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="Slider">
            <div class="slider_img">
              <img src="http://cdn.allsteamboat.com/images/content/5454_dLX8W_Steamboat_Springs_Colorado_Tours_md.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="images">
            <div class="pics">
              <img class="snaps" src="https://turcotravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cappadocia.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="pics">
              <img class="snaps" src="https://www.orbitz.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Albuquerque_International_Balloon_Fiesta_snowpeak-e1315595588824.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="Info">
          <div class="About_Us">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting indutry. Lorem Ipsum has been Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
              typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been Lorem
              Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
              Lorem Ipsum has Lorem Ipsum is simply dummytextoftheprintingandtypesettingindustry.LoremIpsum.............</p>
          </div>
          <div class="button">
            <button type="button">READ MORE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="text">
            <img src="https://www.orbitz.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Albuquerque_International_Balloon_Fiesta_snowpeak-e1315595588824.jpg" />
            <h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
            <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, eros leo molestie
              velit, nonegestas augue nulla</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <!-- <img src="GRProvider/Img_5.jpg" /> -->
            <h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
            <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, eros leo molestie
              velit, nonegestas augue nulla</p>
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <!-- <img src="GRProvider/Img_6.jpg" /> -->
            <h4> PRODUCT INFORMATION </h4>
            <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam tristique tristique any varius. Donec nec vestibulum ligula. Aenean turpis do feugiat a luctus in, rhoncus risus. Maecenas dui\vitae consequat massa imperdietut. elit ut tempus lobortis, eros leo molestie
              velit, nonegestas augue nulla</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
          <h3> Copyright by Bitsprovider.com </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```